# How to get Random Locations inside same congrestional district in US?

Tags: geolocation

I am using a person street address to get latitude and longitude and then determine their congressional district using [sunlight congress api](http://sunlightlabs.github.io/congress/districts.html) I am getting the district properly. But i want to pin these users to map but with concerns to privacy i want to pin them in scrambled location but not outside of their district. How can i do this? is there any api that will allow me to generate random location inside same congressional district?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier/better to just set a single "center" spot per district? Also this could be a bit better since entering in the same location twice wont come up with 2 different locations (which would be a problem for some larger congression districts, like Nevada's second).

Comment: Hello, How do i get the center spot per district? Is there any available data set or api for this?

Comment: you could imagine a rectangle around one district, and generate random points within this rectangle, and check for each point if it is inside your desired district. (Monte Carlo method)

Comment: @Absurd-Mind This method would not reliable work, especially for city areas. Look up Florida's 22nd.

Comment: Would it be reliable if i just use city, state and zipcode and geocode it to get latitude and longitude and then use sunlight api to determine the district?

Comment: This is how i meant it, generate random latitude/longitude "near" your desired district (e.g. a rectangle or circle around the district) an determine if the point belongs to the district. Repeat until you found enough points. Problem1: you need to know the size of the district and location. Problem2: it may be inefficient. but it should be reliable. @Dgrin91 where do you see the "not reliable" part?

Comment: If you pick over and over it would technically be reliable, but that is a REALLY bad way to do it. You could end up picking a TON of candidate locations.

Comment: Yes, but that's the point of Monte Carlo Method. But it is possible to precalculate these points offline. Say you create a database with 1000 valid points for each district and everytime you need a new point you take one of these.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind It would be silly to use Monte Carlo every time someone enters an address. You have to either make a reliable algorithm to generate a valid point with little effort, or you determine points before hand and be done with it.